# Access to server being routed through Russia

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-18.04, thunderbird

For 2 days I have been unable to use Thunderbird on my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop to login to my remote production pop3 server (Postfix, Ubuntu 16.04). Access is denied with message authentication failure; rhost=185.244.41.45. When I do a whois on that ip I find it's in the Russian federation. When I login to Apache on that server from my desktop (Firefox) access is allowed. When I login to apache from my phone using firefox access is denied.

Access to other sites and email addresses on that server are unaffected from desktop and phone. What is going on and how do I stop it?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to use another pop3 client?

Comment: mutt -f imap://username@ip_address

Comment: Check the logs on the mail server.

Comment: mutt gave the response Could not connect to xx.xx.xx.xx (Connection refused). Which is what I had already learned from the server log.

Comment: A traceroute didn't show the request going through 185.244.41.45.

Comment: My greater concern is not being able to access Apache from my Android phone. Both Brave and Firefox give connection refused response. Access from Desktop not a problem. Nothing in the Apache log shows an error for my external IP address, so I can't trouble shoot the phone access.

Comment: I found the solution. On Android, the browser was checking the domain registration which expired 2 days ago. On the desktop, only the certificate was being verified. Thunderbird must have been checking the registration also. All good now. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem. On Android, the browsers were checking the domain registration, which expired 2 days ago. On the desktop, only the certificate was being checked. I presume Thunderbird was also checking the registration.